# How to simulate HTTP requests?

Tags: php, http, jquery, networking, request

How to simulate HTTP requests. For example, I want to  simulate request to  insert data into my database, to check safety and reliability of my program. Are there some good tools ?

Comment: You mean a tool that can *make* HTTP requests? One industry standard is curl: http://curl.haxx.se/ (edit: ah, you may mean load testing - Google eg. `server load testing tools`) This isn't a good question for SO, some Googling will get you all the solutions you need.

Comment: I test my web applications by `Acunetix` ,you can modify requests with it too. but if you only want to modify requests, Use [Tamper data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data)

Answer (score 5):

For *nix OS you can use **telnet**, **curl** or **wget** utilites:

**Telnet:**

```
user@host:~$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /api.php?param1=10&param2=20 HTTP/1.1   # here is your request params
Host: localhost                             # required HTTP header
                                            # double ENTER for sending request
```

Check [telnet man-page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?telnet) of your OS for advanced options.

**Curl:**

```
user@host:~$ curl \
--header 'Host: localhost' \
--user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.12) Gecko/ Firefox/10.0.12' \
--no-keepalive \
http://localhost/api.php?param1=10&param2=20
```

Check [curl man-page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?curl) of your OS for advanced options.

**Wget:**

```
user@host:~$ wget http://localhost/api.php?param1=10&param2=20
```

Check [wget man-page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wget) of your OS for advanced options.

**FYI** if you choose **curl** then you'll allow to use power of *nix shell: **grep**, **sed**, [output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21) and a lot of other useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try from the server side cURL is definitely the easiest way. Since you tagged this question with PHP here is a simple PHP script that simulates a POST request.

```
<?php
$url = "http://yoursite.com/yourscript.php";
$postdata = array (
    "name" => "Joe",
    "address" => "Some street",
    "state" => "NY",
);

$req = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($req);
```

If you want to try requests from the browser there are very good extensions for both Chrome and Firefox. For example (for chrome) [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) or [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

Answer (score 1):

In order to test your PHP application, you can use a testing framework like: [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html)

```
<?php
require_once('simpletest/browser.php');

$browser = &new SimpleBrowser();
$browser->get('http://php.net/');
$browser->click('reporting bugs');
$browser->click('statistics');
$page = $browser->click('PHP 5 bugs only');
preg_match('/status=Open.*?by=Any.*?(\d+)<\/a>/', $page, $matches);
print $matches[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[HTTPie](https://httpie.org/doc) consists of a single "**http**" command designed for painless debugging and interaction with HTTP servers, RESTful APIs, and web services. It can be used on all platforms.

Use Github API to post a comment on an issue with authentication:

```
$ http -a USERNAME POST https://api.github.com/repos/jkbrzt/httpie/issues/83/comments body='HTTPie is awesome! :heart:'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try HTTP request at https://w3webtool.com/http-request-method

You can fill out your parameter and simulate your http request method.